# What is missing in Firefox to support Vue.js debug within PhpStorm?

Tags: vue.js, debugging, firefox, phpstorm

According to [PhpStorm documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/vue-js.html#vue_running_and_debugging_debug):

> Debugging of Vue.js applications is only supported in Google Chrome and in other Chromium-based browsers.

People like [Jonathan Bossenger](https://deliciousbrains.com/debugging-php-javascript-phpstorm/) already tried to circumvent this dependency and make it work with Firefox anyway, but only to come with conclusion like:

> Even if you try to edit the available list of browsers and enable Firefox it won’t come up as an option. Believe me, I tried!

Which lead to the question: what is integrated within Chrome/Chromium which is not present in Firefox, leading to this deficiency in development facility?

Comment: It's not Vue.js specific -- it is the same for any JavaScript. See the same note here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/debugging-javascript-in-chrome.html

Comment: It used to be possible to debug JS with **Firefox Remote** type of Run/Debug Configuration .. but the last version that has it seems to be 2021.1 only (see that version docs: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2021.1/run-debug-configuration-firefox-remote.html ). ALSO CHECK this thread: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360010846880-Webstorm-Debug-Javascript-in-browser-keeps-defaulting-to-Chrome-even-though-I-set-Firefox-to-the-default

Comment: Right now -- watch after https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14987 I guess.

Answer (score 2):

We used to support Firefox remote debugging (but without source maps) through the **FireFox Remote** run configuration, but our solution doesn't work in the latest Firefox versions due to changes in the protocol, and there doesn't seem to be an easy way to fix it. We've made some progress recently, but there are still some blocking issues.

Related tickets: [WEB-45986](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-45986), [WEB-48076](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-48076), [WEB-2337](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-2337)